# Failing to send test email

Tags: wordpress, civimail, email, permissions, testing

I'm trying to send a test email to myself but it keeps showing me this message:*"Could not identify any recipients. Perhaps your test group is empty, or you tried sending to contacts that do not exist and you have no permission to add contacts".*
My test group is NOT empty. I'm using WordPress. Has anyone had the same problem.
Thank you

Comment: pls confirm that the members of your test Group do not have eg 'do not email' or their emails are 'on hold' etc

Comment: Welcome Adela!  You can help us help you by telling us the version of CiviCRM you're using (visible at the bottom of any page), as well as whether you're using traditional CiviMail or Mosaico.  Can you confirm that test emails work from **Administer menu » System Settings » Outgoing Email**?

Comment: A similar problem is described here : https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/41754/on-sending-test-for-mailing-i-get-could-not-identify-any-recipients-perhaps