# On sending test for mailing, I get : "Could not identify any recipients. Perhaps your test group is empty..."

Tags: wordpress, civimail, mailing, amazon-ses, aws

I'm setting up civicrm-5.47.2-wordpress with wordpress-5.9.2 on Ubuntu 20.04 running Cyberpanel 2.1, on AWS Lightsail with AWS SES SMTP credentials in CiviCRM Outbound email where 'Save & Send Test Email' works. I can also send individual email to contacts.

But when I create a draft mailing and use 'Send test email to:' or 'Send test email to group', it tells me it is sent, but then I get the "Could not identify any recipients. Perhaps your test group is empty..." message. It also marks those contacts as 'On hold'. (But I can unset the 'On hold' and email individually from CiviCRM.)

There are no clues in ConfigAndLog.

I can't seem to debug this issue. Need some help please.

Answer (score 1):

After setting Enable Debugging, ConfigAndLog showed this error :

> code: 554, response: Message rejected: Email address is not verified.
> The following identities failed the check in region US-EAST-1:
> b.52.83.fa04b192f1638ba4@mydomain.com

SOLUTION (in my case) was to make sure that my bounce account bounce@mydomain.com had the same domain-part setting as my SES-verified domain (mydomain.ca). SES was rejecting mydomain.com (not verified). To clarify, the bounce account is elsewhere, but the "Email address domain (the part after @)" is set to mydomain.ca which is a verified domain in SES.

After making this change, the "Could not identify any recipients. Perhaps your test group is empty..." message vanished and a test mailing was received by all 17 contacts in the Test group.

Comment: ok. so sounds like the warning/error message isn't super helpful

Comment: Actually, I'd be a bit more explicit and say it is useless and misleading.

Comment: are you up for making an issue here? https://lab.civicrm.org/groups/dev/-/issues

Comment: I don't think that it is specific enough to create an issue. It seems to be a catch-all message for a large number of errors.

Comment: I am having the same problem but not sure I understand your solution.  Can you provide an example of the mail account setup?  Assuming that is where you changed your settings?   Are you using AWS SES?  Did you have to make changes there?