# Send Test email not working properly

Tags: civimail

For the 18 months I've been using civiCRM. the "Send Test" on traditional email worked fine.

Now I am getting the message "Could not identify any recipients. Perhaps your test group is empty, or you tried sending to contacts that do not exist and you have no permission to add contacts."
My test group is fine. When I click "Send Test" my test email address is put "On Hold."
If I send to the test group, everyone in the group is put "On Hold."

Any idea why this is happening?

My civiCRM instance
civiCRM: 5.40.3
Drupal: 7.80

Comment: A similar question was asked recently: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/41754/on-sending-test-for-mailing-i-get-could-not-identify-any-recipients-perhaps - does the answer there help?

Answer (score 1):

Try checking your SMTP settings. (I received that message when I changed the password for that account, but didn't update CiviCRM's Outgoing Mail settings.)

Comment: This - "Save and Send Test Email" will also show you any errors with your SMTP configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a patch to the sparkpost extension. Prior to that it was reporting a similar issue so maybe check the version of sparkpost (if you are using it) and try upgrading the extension.